# Is there a PAM Standard?

Tags: linux, solaris, pam, standard

Related to [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/24798398?noredirect=1) I have. Since it's more or less really a SO question through and through, I won't go into the whole spiel. My platform question is this: Is there an industry standard somewhere that specifies how various aspects of PAM should operate?

Comment: No. There isn't.  Looking at your tags:  the PAM implementation on Solaris varies a fair bit from Linux'  (or the other way around, since Solaris' version is older).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's specified [by the OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/8329799/) (the body specifying Unix) and [by the Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libpam.html).

I don't know how well those are followed on the various Unices/Linuces though.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) is also a good reference.